# NSSavePanel - Adding a select menu

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nssavepanel

I have an app which uses an NSSavePanel.

The app is a *video editing app*, and I need this save panel to **display a selection menu** for the format of the video.

How could I do that ?

Here is a simple code:

```
NSSavePanel *mySavePanel = [NSSavePanel savePanel];
//Code to add a selection menu
[mySavePanel runModal];
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easy, use an accessory view. This is simply a view you can store in your XIB or create programmatically and set using NSSavePanel's `setAccessoryView:` It's displayed under the folder picker control.

After the save panel is dismissed, you can pull whatever values you need from it.